# Combining scores with different ranges, magnitudes and distributions

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, scoring-algorithm

I am trying to combine a few different metrics into a single metric, then attempt to compare that single metric when I change the input metrics values. These input values must also have an adjustable weight (or 'importance').

These metrics might have different ranges and distributions.

For example, I could have the metrics:
$A$ [Range: 0, 1] Grows Linearly
$B$ [Range: 0, 1] Grows Exponentially
$C$ [Range: 0, 1000] Grows Linearly

With weights $Wa, Wb, Wc$

Combining them linearly without any normalization is clearly flawed, eg. $AW_a + BW_b + CW_c$, as the weights are meaningless due to the different magnitudes, distributions etc.
There may be a way or normalizing these values between $0...1$, but I do not know if that will fix the problem of comparing distributions.

I've also attempted $(A^{W_a})(B^{W_b})(C^{W_c})$ but I think this also has problems when one of the terms is 0, and also fails to account for different distributions sensibly. I figure just adding 1 would fix the first problem, however the second problem still stands.

How would I combine these scores? Even some direction as to further reading would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused by the B distribution growing exponentially -- which I think means a histogram of the values would be increasing exponentially -- and yet there is an upper cap oon the values such that they are all in the range of [0,1].  Could it be that they are frequencies, i.e. normalized counts? For example the original data was integer counts, and then they've all been divided by their sum, to bring them into [0,1].

If so, try taking the log of the counts BEFORE they were divided by their sum.  That way (1) you'll get positive numbers, where higher means higher, as opposed to taking logs of the [0,1] values, since that would yield negative logs, and (2) the distribution will no longer have such an exponential shape.  The ranks will not be disturbed, but the higher values will be much less high, and the lower values will be raised, which also means that (3) small differences between the small values will become more important.

After taking the logs, do a linear transform to bring them back to [0,1].  And Divide C by 1000.  Voilá!